# Json parser and loop scheme

Tags: javascript, json

How can I loop my json file using my script, eg: I should choose whether to loop Schema A or Schema B.

**My json file is:**

```
{
   "A":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "title":"Primo"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "title":"Secondo"
      }
   ],
   "B":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "title":"Primo"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "title":"Secondo"
      }
   ]
}
```

Maybe setting a variable so as to define the scheme I have to display

**My javascript file is:**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "myTutorials.txt";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    myFunction(myArr);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
  var out = "";
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += arr[i].id + ' - ' + arr[i].title + '<br>';
  }
  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: `myFunction(myArr.A);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "myTutorials.txt";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var obj= JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    myFunction(obj, 'A');
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(obj, key) {
  var arr = obj[key];
  var out = "";
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += arr[i].id + ' - ' + arr[i].title + '<br>';
  }
  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you presented as JSON file is a response form network and is passed to `myFunction`, then why not to do something like:

```
let myRootArray;
if(/* some confitions */) {
  myRootArray = myArr.A
} else {
  myRootArray = myArr.B
}
myFunction(myRootArray );
```

Beside that, your names are a bit confusing,  `var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);`, while `JSON.parse` will return object, not an array.